# Synthesis of new elements with Pb-126 as particle projectile?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, elements, particle-accelerators

Why isn’t Pb-126 used in the synthesis of new elements as a projectile against a target instead of Ca-48 considering it is heavier and has a double magic number of protons and neutrons, just like Ca-48?

Comment: It also has a higher nuclear charge, so a larger Coulomb barrier to overcome.

Comment: Is it that big of an issue? As far as I understand, the biggest problem towards synthesizing new elements is getting the atom to “stick” and as such energy isn’t an issue, it is just the luminosity (L). Considering the heating issues posed by introducing heavier element targets like Einsteinium and their costs, why isn’t using a heavier projectile seen as worth it?

Comment: This review may help you https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed062p392

Comment: I assume you mean Pb-208?